# Cuando envío una variable a la vista desde el controlador pierdo el css

Tags: php, laravel, variables, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

Tengo mi plantilla de **bootstrap** en `layouts`, hago los `extends` de mi platilla, y en `views` tengo mi carpeta *"permisos"*, que es donde está `ejemplo.blade.php` este es mi controlador:

```
public function ejemplo() {
    $var=6;
    return view('Permisos/ejemplo')->with('var',$var);

}
```

y esta la ruta

```
Route::get('ejemplo/{var}','PermissionController@ejemplo')->name('ejemplo');
```

pero cuando mando la variable pierdo la plantilla de **bootstrap**, así es como la mando llamar en `ejemplo.blade`

```
@extends('layouts.plantilla')
@extends('layouts.menu')
@section('main')
   <h1>este un texto de ejemplo {{$var}}</h1>

@endsection
```

si no le mando la variable, o más bien si modifico el código para que no reciba nada el **css** funciona bien, pero si lo mando deja de funcionar.

He checado la consola del navegador y me da varios errores, todos el mismo, dice

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)"

me da con todos las opciones de **bootstrap** que uso, los botones, tablas, etc.

Comment: abre al consola de desarrollo del navegador por favor y en la pestaña console verifica si aparece algún error; en caso afirmativo edita tu pregunta y agregalo

Comment: Prueba colocando el @extends('layouts.plantilla') dentro de la plantilla 'layouts.menu'

Comment: he checado la consola del navegador y me da errores de este tipo "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" eso con todas las opciones de bootstrap que utilizo, los charts, tables, buttons etc.

Comment: Hace falta saber por ejemplo en cual de esas plantillas que invocas tienes el llamado a los archivos de bootstrap, el error 404 es por que no logra encontrar donde estan dichos archivos, te sugiero editar y agregar el código de dicha plantilla

Answer (score 0):

Tu ruta señala que el campo var es obligatorio, por otra parte, te llevará a otro sitio que probablemente es 404

Si necesitas que var sea opcional, modifica la ruta por

```
Route::get('ejemplo/{var?}','PermissionController@ejemplo')->name('ejemplo')
```

La función debe incluir tambien un parámetro y en este caso con un valor por default

```
public function ejemplo($var=6) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Al tu indicar return **view** con las variables mediante el metodo **with** estas diciendole a laravel que la variable este presente en la vista mas no en la url por el metodo get, las vistas y las url son cosas diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Para la pregunta original... todo tiene que ver en como pones la referencia a tus archivos de estilos
ejemplo
href="css/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css
lo correcto
href="/css/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css

Solo añade la diagonal "/" al inicio de la referencia para que apunte correctamente